# undefined method `SomePresenter' for SomeNamespace:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, module, namespaces, presenter

I user namespace to create some module in Rails. It works fine in controllers, models, but something is wrong with presenters which are in a `presenters` path.

This is one of presenters, without namespace:

```
class MainPresenter < Struct.new(:main, :current_user)
  extend Ext::CollectionPresenter

  def as_json
    {
      something: SomeNamespace::SomePresenter(main.something)
    }
  end

end
```

And this is the presenter in `presenters/some_namespace/some_presenter.rb`

```
class SomeNamespace::SomePresenter < Struct.new(:something, :options)
  extend Ext::CollectionPresenter

  def as_json
    # some hash here
  end

end
```

I get `undefined method 'SomePresenter' for SomeNamespace:Module` error. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomePresenter` is a class and you are using it as a method. Hence, the error.
Use it as below :

```
something: SomeNamespace::SomePresenter.new(main.something)
```

Comment: @ciembor Please accept the answer as it will help others that the suggested answer worked.(and indirectly me too :))